# Interpreting notation for Lie group representations

Tags: representation-theory, definition, lie-groups

I have a problem with the follwing setup:

Let $\phi:SU(2) \to GL(3,\mathbb{C})$ be a representation and let $\psi:SU(2) \to P_2$. Where $P_2$ is spanned by the monomials $x^2,xy,y^2$ over $\mathbb{C}.$
The map acts by:

$$\psi(P)(f)(x,y) = f((x,y)\phi(P^{-1})^T)$$ 
I dont understand what $(x,y)\phi(P^{-1})^T$ means. Surely $\phi(P^{-1})^T$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix so this is not defined? Thanks.

Comment: You are right, something has gone wrong there. As far as I can tell, they are looking to make the group act on those polynomials rather than on the usual vectors, which is usually done by just identifying the standard basis with those three polynomials. Not quite sure what they precisely mean here (seems like an attempt to do this in a basis independent way).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $\phi:SU(2)\to GL(V)$ is a representation, then the dual representation $\phi^*:SU(2)\to GL(V^*)$ for $V^*=\hom(V,\mathbb{C})$ is defined by $$\phi^*(P) f=f\circ \phi(P)^{-1}$$ for $P\in SU(2)$ and $f\in V^*$.  (This is so that $\langle f,v\rangle = \langle \phi^*(P)f,\phi(P)v\rangle$ for all $f\in V^*$, $v\in V$, and $P\in SU(2)$, where $\langle f,v\rangle$ is the canonical pairing.)

Let $V$ denote a $2$-dimensional representation of $SU(2)$.  Let $C(V)$ denote the set of all continuous $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions defined on $V$, which includes, for example, polynomially defined functions, inside of which both $V^*$ and $P_2$ are subsets.

$C(V)$ is an $SU(2)$ representation in the same way $V^*$ is: $\phi^*(P) f=f\circ \phi(P)^{-1}$.  Written with arguments, this looks more like $(\phi^*(P) f)(v)=f(\phi(P)^{-1}v)$ with $v\in V$.  With $v$ as a column vector, this looks like
$$(\phi^*(P) f)\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix} = f\left(\phi(P)^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\right),$$
and by transposing the arguments, we can write $v$ as a row vector to match "$f(x,y)$" notation like so:
$$(\phi^*(P) f)(x,y) = f((x,y)(\phi(P)^{-1})^T).$$

Hopefully this helps unravel the mystery.

Comment: So your guess is that they meant for $\phi$ to be $2$-dimensional rather than $3$-dimensional?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I missed the part that $V$ is somehow supposed to be $3$-dimensional, and I imagine someone was thinking ahead to the fact that $\operatorname{dim}(P_2)=3$.  I'm assuming the point of the question is to study $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V$, the symmetric square of an $SU(2)$ representation.  (I can't think of a way to use $P_2$ to study the symmetric square of a $3$-dimensional $SU(2)$ representation.)

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess as well.